# What happens when a switch goes offline? and can they be easily exploited through open wifi?

Tags: router, switch, wifi

I have two simple questions regarding switches:

When a router/ proxy server/ dns host fails, they tend to not allow any packets through. Is this the same with a switch?

A switch is connected to 3 areas: a open wireless access point, internal network and a router connected to the internet. If a user connects to the open wireless point, primarily designed to only allow the user to connect to the intenet; is it possible for the user to exploit the switch and gain access to the internal network? (Hope this makes sense)

Thanks

Comment: In a properly-designed network, the management interfaces of network devices live on a completely separate VLAN from everything else, so "normal" traffic would never be able to access the management interfaces, open wireless or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without narrowing your question down to specific products, this can only be answered generally.

Typically, if a switch fails all devices that have a connection to that switch will lose connectivity.

As for the switch being exploitable, barring any sort of bug, a properly configured device should not be exploitable by someone connected to an open "guest" wireless network.